# catching value changes in input, when it's not focused

Tags: jquery, focus

i want to create an attribute (e.g. markChanges='true') that will automatically detects if the value of the input has changed, but only if that input is not focused.

(the value could change from js code of course)

How would i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the only solution would be to poll, which means you would have to use [`setInterval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).  Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sa5vn/1/) for an example.  Code is

```
function detectChange(input, interval) {
    var previous = "";

    setInterval( function() {

        var val = $(input).val();
        if (  val != previous ) {
            previous = val;
            alert("Input has changed");
        }

    }, interval);
}

detectChange("input", 100);

setTimeout( function() {
    $("input").val("some value!");
}, 4000);
```

Comment: There's no way to detect changes without polling for value?! there must be a more elegant way... no?

Comment: Not when you dynamically change the value.  The only thing you have is `.change()` but that is based on `focus`.  With that being said, there must be something that's changing the value of your input, which means you can delegate the job to that function instead of letting the input detect it's own changes.

Comment: yeah, but since i have a *lot* of inputs that changes the values of other inputs, it's going to make my code rather messy.. what do u mean when u say that change is based on focus?

Comment: `.change()` only gets fired if the input has been `focusin` and `focusout`.  What you CAN do is instead of using `val()` to set the value you can write your own which sets the value but at the same time changes any other attributes you want.